# How can I view the live view of a Camera via WLan using Python - Solved

Tags: python, sockets, udp, video-streaming, pickle

I have a Panasonic camera (DC-FZ82) that is able to transfer a live view over its own WLAN. I have written a program that sends http requests to the camera (like this: http://192.168.54.1/cam.cgi?mode=getstate). To start the liev View this command is send http://192.168.54.1/cam.cgi?mode=startstream&value=49152, then the camera starts to send the live view with UPD from its port (65428) to my port 49152.
[Snippet of Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b5bi.png)

My problem is that I don´t know how I can process the data that´s being received from `data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)` so that it can be shown as a live video.

Thank you and sorry for the messy code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
import pickle
import socket
import time

host = '192.168.54.10'
port = 49152
max_length = 30000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((host, port))

frame_info = None
buffer = None
frame = None

# Die IP-Adresse der Kamera
camera_ip = "192.168.54.1"

commands=["mode=setsetting&type=device_name&value=MI%205",
          "mode=camcmd&value=playmode",
          "mode=camcmd&value=video_recstart",
          "mode=camcmd&value=video_recstop",
          "mode=camcmd&value=capture",
          "mode=getstate",
          "mode=setsetting&type=iso&value=80",
          "mode=camctrl&type=touch&value=0/0&value2=on",
          "mode=camcmd&value=touchafrelease",
          "mode=startstream&value=49152",
          "mode=accctrl&type=req_acc&value=4D454930-0100-1000-8000-A0C9A018A734&value2=SM-G9350",
          "mode=setsetting&type=device_name&value=SM-G9350",
          "mode=getinfo&type=allmenu",
          "mode=getinfo&type=curmenu",
          "mode=camcmd&value=recmode",
          "mode=getinfo&type=lens"]

# Funktion, um einen Befehl an die Kamera zu senden und das Ergebnis zurückzugeben - function for sending a commad to the cam
def send_command(command):
    url = f"http://{camera_ip}/cam.cgi?" + command
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(url)
    print(response.text)
    return response.text

if True:
    while True:
        # Befehle anzeigen
        for i, command in enumerate(commands):
            print(f"{i}: {command}")

        # Eingabeaufforderung anzeigen und Eingabe vom Benutzer lesen - Read user input
        choice = input("Befehl eingeben: ")

        # Befehl auswählen und an die Kamera senden - choose command and send to cam
        if choice.isdigit() and int(choice) < len(commands):
            send_command(commands[int(choice)])
        elif choice.isdigit() and int(choice)==99:
            break
        else:
            send_command(choice)

        # Live-Video anzeigen - show live view
        if choice.isdigit() and int(choice) == 9:
            
            while True:
                #print("True")
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)
                #print("Adresse: ")
                #print(address)
                print("Daten: ")
                print(data)
                print(len(data))

                if len(data) < 28000:
                    frame_info = pickle.loads(data)
                    print("Frame_info:")
                    print(frame_info)
                    print("len(data) < 100")
                    if frame_info:
                        nums_of_packs = frame_info["packs"]

                        for i in range(nums_of_packs):
                            print("Data, address = sock.recvfrom")
                            data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)

                            if i == 0:
                                buffer = data
                            else:
                                buffer += data

                        frame = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint8)
                        frame = frame.reshape(frame.shape[0], 1)

                        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            
                        if frame is not None and type(frame) == np.ndarray:
                            print("streaming...")
                            cv2.imshow("Stream", frame)
                            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                                break
                            
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Data from "print(data)":

```
b'f\x1a\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xc9\xa0\x18\xa74\x00!\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x92\x00\n\x00\n\x00\x01H\xff`\xff\x01\x01\x01@\xbb\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x02\xf9\x01\x00\x02\xf9\x01\x00\x0b\x00\x01\x00\xfe\x00\x01\x00\x07\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\xff\x01*M\t\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x07\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0f\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x03\x00\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x10\x10\x08\x18\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10 \x10\x18\x18\x18\x10 ((( (((008@0008(0H888@@HH(HP8PPPHH@HH\x01\x10\x08\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10  \x100H0(HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x01h\x02\x80\x03\x01!\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x01\xa2\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2\x81\x08\x14B\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\t#3R\xf0\x15br\xd1\n\x16$4\xe1%\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xdd\x00\x04\x00\x00\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xf3\x11\x9c\xf5\x14\xa7\xd7\x07\x1e\xd5\x95\x9a\xb9\xbd\xc6g\x92x\xa4\xc8\xe3\x9e\xb56\xf2\x1a\x1e\x0f\xd6\x9cNzS]\x01\x8d=\x0f\xb50\xe3\'\xde\x93\xdfq\x88\x0ep)\xf9\xcf>\xb5Q\x10\xfc\xfab\x90\x9cz\xd2\x01\xb9\xe9K\xbb\xd8\xd1\xa0\\3\xda\x94\xe4\x0c\x9aK\xa8w\x138\xe0w\xedJ\x0fa\xdf\xebC\xf5\x0b\x81\xe3\'\x9ei3\xcfSF\xddA\x8a\x1b\x8f\xce\x8c\xe4~T\xc0p\xe7\xad7=\xe90c\x81\xcey\x1cQ\xc6z\xfbS[\x05\xc6\xf7\xcf\xf2\xa7\x12\x01\xea8\xefDu\xea\x0cL\xf3\xd4s\xfa\xd1\x9fqC\xea\t\xe8\x1c\xf4\xcd\x1dh@\xf7\x17?\xad\x19\xef\x9akq\xa13\xce\x7f:NqR\xc1\x07\xe1\xfc\xe8\'\xbehk`\x1c3\xc1\xfet\xa0\xf3\xf4\xa7\r\xc3qH\xef\xc7\xad \xc9\x14\x90\x0b\xd8~T\xa2\x98\x0b\xef\xc5/\xe5In\x0cS\xecsJ\x0eh\xb8\x0e\xe6\x97\x1c\x8aN\xe0.3\xd4\xd3\xb1B\x06D\xe0g\xebN^\xb4\x0c~:\x93\x9aLs\xc7\xd6\x92z\x00\xa3<t\xe2\x9f\x8e;R\xea\x03:\x9e\xb5aE\x1dF\xc91\x9eqK\x8e\xde\xb4\xc4\x1b})\xdbz\xe2\x9a\xf5\x01\xa0s\xcdM\x9c\x0c\xe2\xabp\xd0\x81\x8f\'\x9e\xb4\xe5\x1c\xe3\xd6\x92\xd8\xb4N\xbd\x89>\x94\xf3\xf7y\xa44=\x14\x9cg\xbdN\xee#\xd8\x9cs\x9f\xe5Ik$)\xbb\\\xe7\x95\xcb2\xb1=MX=OJ\xda\xb8\xf2\x9d]A\xbf\\\xf1K\xef\x83\xcdg\xf3;\x99\x04\xb3\xac[A#-\xfc\xab~\xd2\xf9nQ\x12\xdf\x80\x83\x04\xb6q\x9f\xa0\xad(/#\xcf\xcd\xaa]\xa8\xdc\x96W\x9ehd\x8f\xce\xd9\xb3\x9c\xaey\xfc\xeb\x83\xd4L{\xf0&\x99\xd8\x7f{\x15\xb6\x968\xd1(bO$\xd0\x08\xe0\xf1\\\xceF\xed\x01\xeb\x9fN\xf4\xd3\x91\x8a\x18\\]\xd8\xce\x7f\xa5;\'\xf2\xfchZ\xf5)\x81\xeb\x8ai\xf4\xf4\xf4\xa2B\x13\xd8v\xa3=\xbfJ\x1f\xa8\x0e\xcf\x07\x9fJ\x0f\xd6\x95\xac\x01\x93\xfc\xc57#<\xf7\xa7\xa5\xc1\x0e\x078\x14\xa0\x8f^\x94\xd0;j\x19\xa0z\xfdi|\xc4\xde\x82\x93\xeb\xfeM#w\xc5\x1aj\x1a\xd8L\xf4\'?\xfdj3\xc9\xa4\xae\x03\x814\xa7\x9e\xddh]F&H \xfaR\xe7\xb8\xa7\x1d\xc1\x8b\x9f\xa5!\xea}\xbe\xb4D\x1d\xc6\xe7\x81K\xbb\xb7qC\xea\x0ba}\x08\xa3=x\xebM\xee\x0e\xc1\xcfL\x9a:\xfe4\x93\xdf@\x13\x9c\xf7\xe6\x8e\x84`P\xf5@(\xe3>\xdf\xce\x90\x1e\xd9\xa5\xdbPC\xf1\x9e\xfd)G\xe1M\x82\xd0^\xbf\x8d\'J@\xc7u\xe0\xd2\xf0\x7f\x1am\xf9\x8fq\xdd\x8d\x02\x96\xc0;\x06\x97\x19\xe2\xa4\x05\xc1\xe6\x9d\x8f\xd2\x9b\xb5\xd8n(\xeb\xc8\x14\xfcR`F\xc3&\x91?\x1aoD\x86I\x82\x00\xa4#\xb5!\n\xa2\xa4#\x8eM\x0b\xa8\xc8\xc0\xf9\xbe\x95eT\xfa\xd2i\x0c~?ZP;\xfa\xd0\xac\'q\xd8\xfa\xf3R\xe0\x1e*\xba\x8a\xe48\xa5&\x9e\xc8h`\xe7?\x8dJ\xa3\xf5\xa7\'\xa6\xe5\xd8\x9c\x0c\xf1\x8a\x95S"\xa1\xe9pd\xd8X\xd7q\xc7\x1e\xb5\xce\x1b\xef7R\x8e0A\x03\xcc\xc8?\xee\x9at\x15\xe4Ewh\xb28\xb1\xfb\xb3W\x0f>\xb5\xb5SL\x9f\xed\x8d\xc7\xd7\x8f\xca\x98\xecW\x85\\\xb3}\xd1\xefYY\xb6\x8e\xd95\x14\xcc\x99\xf2\xad\x99U\xcb7QZ6W*\xa7\x11\xab.\x07$`\x9a\xde\xd6H\xf1\xaa\xb7)7\xdc\x9aO\x12\xdd\xdb\x83\x0f\x97\t\'\x90\xc0\xe4\xd75su%\xcc\x8f4\xc7,\xfd\xbd(OQT\x8b\x83\xb3e\xb2{\xe0\x8c\xd1\x9cq\x8a\xc5\x9b\x0b\x9e\xa74P\xef\xdc7\x1b\xec{\xd0A\x00Q+\\\x1e\xc3\x81<\xe6\x94\x9fsK{\r\x0c\'\xb1\xa4\xe4q\x9f\xff\x00]T\x96\xfa\x88PI=\xe9s\xd3\xf1\xa4\x95\xfa\x80\x0e\xe2\x8e\xc7${\xd3w\x0e\xafA\t\xf5\xc5.z\xd2\xe9\xb8u\x1d\x9fznO?\x85\t\xd8\x19&OjC\xc9\xa1Z\xe0\xc4\xe0\x8e\xff\x00\xa57>\x82\x89n\x03\x81\xc58\x10x\xcd-;\x8c\x0e=i\x0eG\xaei\xbdC@\x07\x9f\xa5;\xaf>\xbfZkf\'\xea4\xe0\x9a\x018\xfa\xd2\x04\xc5\xeci(\x93\xbd\x80vs\x93FO \xf6\xa3^\xe0/<\xf4\xe6\x90\n\x18\xd8\x13\xd4R\xe3\xbe)\x00\xeeq\xd7\xa5\x07\xa56\x02\x8f\xa7J^OJ[\x80\xa0w\xc5(\xe3\xa5\x008\x0fZP;\xd4\x8cp\xf6\xc7?\x8d\x1e\xfcS@\xf7\x1eG_z1\xcd\x0e\xfa\x82\x1d\x8c\xf1\xeb\xfc\xaa\\g\xad\x00\xc8\xdcz\xf7\xa4\x02\x94\x81\x12c#>\xb4m\xedI\x8d\x00^\x9d)\xec8\xa4\xb7\x01\x8a\xb5e@\x1d\xa9\xb1\x92c\xd7\xbd.?Z/a|\xc3o\xe9N\xfaU&\x0cLg$w\xa8\xdb\x04\xe7\xd6\x9az\x84\x04\x03\x91\x8a\x9d{\x1c\xd2\x93\xbd\xcb\'^\xdf\xfdz\xb2\x8b\xdd\xb1P\xc1\x98:\xbe\xa4\xb1\xa9\x8d\x1b\x9fj\xe74}\xd3j\nI<\x89I\xc7\xfb\xa6\xb7\xc3++\xf79\xf1O\xa1\xac\x84\xe6\x01\xefZ\x04~\xbfZx\x9d\xd1\xd3\x93\xedPa\x15#\xdb*\xaf\x98\xce\xc0\xe0\x81\x83\xd0R\xa0\x9bf\x99\xa4\xf9i\xdb\xb9\xcd]]|\xcd\x1c[03\x82+<\xbb\x11\x8d\xcd\x83\xda\xb4\x93<\xd13I\x93\x9eH\xa0\r~01M\xc7\x1f^\xf5\x8d\xfc\xcd\xa4\x1e\xf8\xebJ\x0f\x7f_\xe7Oq\xa198\xe3\xad\x1cu\xc5(\x83\xd8L\xf2\x0eG\xebN\x04v4k\xdc.!\xebHq\xc7\x18\xe9F\xb7` \xcf\'=iA\xeeq\xf8\xd0\xac\x81\\\\\xfa\x8aJ\x1fQ\x89\xedJ\x0e:\xe6\x87\xd4Hu(4\t\xbb\x06z\xf3N\xcf\xafz4\x1d\xc6\x90{v\xa3\xafS@\x98r{\xf4\xa7d\xe79\x14$;\x0e\x078$\xf5\xa4\xf4\xc68\xe74.\xa1p#\xdc\xd2p2@\xfc\xe9\xec\'\xb0\x1cz\x8a1\xc9\xeb\xcd\x17\xf2\x01s\x9fZ8\xc9\xcfjCh\x07\xa9\xa5\xf6"\x80\xb8\xa3\x8ex\xe2\x8f\xca\x80\xd43\xc9\xcf\xd6\x94\n\x1a\x06?\x1d=\xa8\xe4\xd2\x04.>\xb4\xe01\x8a7\x18\xec{\xd2\xe3\'\x9cP\xf5\x0e\xe2\xe2\x9c\x07\xe9In6.:\xfbR\xe3\x07\xfc\xf5\xa0B\x81\xfa\xd3\xf0O\xe1J\xfa\x80\xa0T\x80q\xf5\xfetu\x18\x8c\xa4\xe6\x9a\x174;\xea\x08~8\xa3\x1c\xd2[l\x08x\x02\x95\x80\xfc\xa8Z\x8cz\xaf\x1d*@\xbdqI\xdd\x80\xef\xa8\x14\x00E?\x98\x83\xe9\xde\x9d\x82*\x93\xdf@\x14\x0c\xfe5\x1b\xa1=(Ka\xc7r=\xa4u\xa9\x91\t<\x8aU44."c$\xe2\xb3u-Q-beV\x195\n<\xcd\nN\xc9\x9c\r\xc5\xcc\x97\x0e\xee\xcckS@]\xda\x82\x003\x94\x9b\xff\x00A5\xd9\x15dq\xcd\xdd\xb3MN\x1a\xd4\x0f\xe2\'\xa5h\x9cc\xaej1;\xa3\xb7\'\xdad39\x8e9\x1f<\x80M`\xdd\xea\x12\xce\xa22z\x00\x18\x8e\xe2\x8a\r\xeb\xa8g\x1f`\xcd\xebS\xc5mqq\xc40L\xf8\xfe\xe0cZn\xce\x16<Y]\xf9\xc9\x0f\xd9\xe6\x0f)\xc2\xa9\x04d\xd7Qo\xe1#\x8f\xf4\xcb\xf8\x11\x8fT\\\x13\x9am[p0\xb2ON\xd4\x0fPzW?Cp=;Q\xc1\xfc)\xc7A&\x03\x9c\x9c\xf5\xa5\xe4\x9cz\xd2\x067\xf04t\xc0\xa5}F\xc7\x0e\xc7\xad\x1f\\\xfd)\xb1\\i\xe7\x9cS;\xd3~\x80\xc7\xe7\x19<\xd2d\x8e\x80\xd2\x1a\xd8\x07\xbex\xa0s\xebE\x84;\x9e\x9e\xb4\x99\xe3\x929\xa3@\x0fZx<\xfdh`\x85=\xb1\xde\x90\x81\xcd\ry\x82\xeb\xa0\x03\x9e\xe3\xbd(\xeb\x91\xc5\x1bu\x05\xb8\xbd\x8f\xb5/9\xc9\xefs\x8aQ\x8c\xf5\xa4\x9f\x981\xd8\'\xad\x00}hL\x18\xecq\xda\x9c)\x0cv)q\xfa\xd0\xc3\xb8\xecs\xcfjx\x140\xea;\x1e\xd4b\x86\x02\xe3\xebO\xc7\xd6\x90\xd8\xecS\xd5{\xfe"\x8108\xe7"\x90/aKA\xeb\xdcv\xd3\xc8\xc5\x18\xa2\xe0\x89\x00\xa3\x04\x9eh\xba\x04L\xab\xda\x9f\xb6\x92\x06\x05On\xd4\x98\xe0\xd3\x88\x06\xdaS\x9e\x95K@\x14\x0e\xbdi\xdbI=)j8\x8b\xe5g\xb5H\x14 \xc9\xc7\x14\x9e\xe5\xdc\xc3\xd4\xb5d\x85\x19#<\xf4\xe2\xb8{\x9b\x99.$.\xccy\xadp\xf1\xb6\xb60\xc4\xcf\xa1\x08<{\x9a\xe8\xbc?\x93\x7f\xdf\xe5\x8en\x99\xfe\xe9\xadLK\x81s=\x90\xfe\xe9c\x81Z\xcc\xd1\xa0/+0\x0b\xd7\x1c\x93\xec=\xeaq\x1b\xe8wen\xd0\xa8\xcd\x19\x0e\x9b\x15\xa8\xfbu\xb3\xa1\xb8\x18Tb\x0b\x11\xf8W\x9e\xdc\x08\xc4\xd2\x08\xc3\x05$\xe3&\xaa*\xcbc\x97\x11VU\x1e\xa6\xee\x81\xa7\xd9\\\xbc\x93\xdf\x1c\xacg\xe5C\x9c\x13\xdf>\xd5\xbdu\xaf\\\xab\x18\xf4\xc8\xe0H\xa2\x18\x05\x86\x07\x1e\x82\x9cL\xde\xa4\x16\xf77\xba\x80\x12\\\xca7[\xe7n@\x18c\xd2\xaaZi\x93\xdd\xdc1y\x00 \xb6]\x8f?\x90\xaaK@0\xfb\x11\x81G8\x03\xads\xeem!\xd9\x1d\xfbb\x90\xf4\xc1\x1d~\x98\xa3K\x82a\x9e9=y\xcd\'<d\x8f\xd6\x95\xae1y\xf4\xff\x00\nA\xd7\xafJO}\xc2\xe83\xc1\xe7\xf1\xa5\xfav\xa7k\xdcL\\g\'\x9a\x8f8\'=\xff\x00\x9d\x1d@:\xf7\xebK\xcf\xaf\xff\x00\xae\x85\xa5\x83p$\x9c\xff\x00ZQ\x9f\xcf\x9a\x18&/\xaf\xff\x00\xaa\x93\xae:\xd0\xaf\xd8\x00g\x9a^Fs\xde\x84\x0cx\xc6x\xcf\xad!\xc7\xe5F\x81\xa8\x0e\xa4\x9e\xd4\xee\xd4\x0c\x07\xa8\xa0\xf0\x08\xf5\xa1\xadX\xafa\xdc\xe6\x
```

Wireshark file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18vz1yH7yChi32iFBuyNJFVXDlAwjnb7g/view?usp=sharing

Working code:

```
while True:
 cv2.namedWindow("Live View", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) 
          
 data, address = sock.recvfrom(max_length)

 #Löschen vor Marker - Deleting data before marker   
 marker = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb'
 start_index = data.find(marker)

 if start_index != -1:
     image_data = data[start_index:]
     nparr = np.frombuffer(image_data, np.uint8)
     img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                
     # Bild anzeigen
     cv2.imshow("Live View", img)

     if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
          break
     else:
          print("Marker nicht gefunden.")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: do you even know the format of the data in those UDP packets?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think the camera sends frames in MP4 format. But I am not sure.

Comment: that is insufficient information. you'll have to figure this out. there is no way around that. you could provide a wireshark capture and hope that someone will look at it. -- what makes you think that `pickle.loads` is a sensible operation on data produced by something that doesn't use python?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It was just a try if it would work with ´pickle.loads´ - i am a noob, i have provided a screenshot but I guess you mean a wireshark file?

Comment: welcome. to mark a question as answered, you do not edit the question's title and you do not put the solution in the question. you use the site's mechanisms, as demonstrated in the [tour]. -- if you are dissatisfied with answers already given, you can comment on them. if you are satisfied, the [tour] will also show what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The capture appears to contain repeated UDP packets. That's weird.

The payloads of those UDP frames start with a 16 bit length themselves. That's kinda superfluous because UDP already does the framing.

The remainder of the data doesn't quite ring a bell. might very well be proprietary. There is a header section that doesn't change.

***I see a JPEG header***. The ASCII side of Wireshark's hexdump shows actual ASCII, not latin1 or anything, so it shows just a `.` for any bytes above `0x7f`. That hides important information in hexdumps.

I haven't scanned the data for other well-known signatures. You can browse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and check for whatever seems interesting.

Here's the JPG data copied out of the last UDP packet. Your camera appears to see darkness.

[image: last packet]

That means you can find the JPEG header, then just slice the data from there to the end, and decode it.

This is incredibly poor video streaming, both technically and practically. It uses JPEG, which is image compression, not video compression. It wastes data by being "intra". Video compression has used "predictive" frames and motion prediction since at least the 90s ([first developed in 1975!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_coding_format#Motion-compensated_DCT)). Those frames rely on data from already decoded frames and build the next frame from that and a little additional information. That saves bandwidth.

Comment: Hey @Christoph Rackwitz thank you very much for your help. The code works and a live View of the camera is shown.